# Filter pivot by keyword

Tags: excel, vba, filter, macros, pivot

I would like my macro to filter my pivot table by a specific keyword - a string of 3 letters ("xxx"). Unfortunately, the string "xxx" can be located anywhere in the text and does not appear after or before a specific number of other letters.

I have tried the following two solutions to filter the pivot in that way, neither of which worked.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Solution 1

```
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("column").ClearAllFilters
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("column"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = False
        End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("column")
    .PivotItems("*xxx*").Visible = True
    End With
```

Solution 2

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("column").strPattern("*xxx*")

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("TEST").PivotFilters.Add _
        Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="123"`

Comment: Excel claims the "_" between "Add" and "Type" is an invalid character. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's a line continuation, just remove it and make it one line or make sure there is a space before it

Comment: That's exactly what i did, but I still get that error:

Comment: .PivotFilters.Add _ Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="303"

Comment: I also tried the following, which did not work either:
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("cloumn").PivotFilters.Add _
FilterType:=xlCaptionContains, DataField:="column", Value1:="123"


Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Do what you want recording it as a macro and see what you're given, it could be that the question isn't leading people to the correct result.  My code was taken from a worksheet where it worked, I filtered for containing 123 and I got the results expected. Can you elaborate a little more on your data.

Comment: I've tried the following solution as well now, which unfortunately did not work either: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotField(column).PivotFilters.Add _
        FilterType:=xlCaptionContains, DataField:="column", Value1:="303"

Comment: I've tried to record a macro, but excel claimed it cannot record this task. The "column" with the relevant data contains very long strings of characters, spaces, numbers and symbols e.g. an entry could look like the following: "Region - 123 - Name of Object  Region2 - 234 - Name of Obejct2" etc. It can be up to 5 or 6 of those objects in one field. Is there any other information that would be helpful?

Comment: That does not seem to work as it would filter the underlying data set rather than the data in the pivot. Not quite sure what you mean. Textfilters do not seem to be an option for the pivot, but I used the captioncontains as outlined above. I suppose I will have to continue to do some manual work...

Comment: When you select from the drop down to select an item from the pivot, you can select "text filters" so try recording that and looking at the code.    apologies, i pasted the code for a filter.

Comment: That's very strange each time I try to either select items from the drop down menu or use the search box in there (which is what I previously did), excel (2013) claims it is "unable to record this action".